# how to locate a name-not-specified file in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, quoting, wildcards

I have a bash like this to easily upload a file to my server:

```
FILE=../"$1"/1.txt
scp 1.txt remoteserver #upload the file to a remote server.
```

The $1 is for input directory and I have a lot of directories. But the txt file in all those directories are not all named "1.txt". What I can confirm is that each directory only contains one txt file.

How do I locate that file in this situation?

Update:

I tried to type `FILE=../"$1"/1.txt`

but when I check the file with:

`if [ -f "$FILE" ]`

I notice it's getting a false even when the file exist.

I figured out that:

`$FILE` is `../test/1.txt`

`"$FILE"` is `../test/*.txt`

So do I have to remove the pair of `"`?

Comment: `FILE=../"$1"/*.txt` See: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob

Comment: @jasonwryan When I use echo $FILE it's working and the output is as expected. But when I use `if [ ! -f "$FILE" ]` it gives a false. So what should I do then?

Comment: Remove the bang: you are negating the test...

Comment: sorry i mean gives true! you can try it yourself.

Comment: `[ -f $FILE ]`...

Comment: I was checking if the file does not exist. Anyway, I've changed. And when I use `[ -f $FILE ]`, it will gives a false. I just tried.

Comment: Works for me...

Comment: I've updated the question, should I use `"` in this case? if so, why? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the wildcard `*` for the name that you don't know. Let's say you set

```
FILE=../"$1"/*.txt
```

Wildcard expansion only happens outside of quotes. `$FILE` variable still has the asterisk in it. So,

```
[ -f "$FILE" ]
```

is equivalent to

```
[ -f "../test/*.txt" ]
```

which wants a literal asterisk in the filename, but

```
[ -f $FILE ]
```

is equivalent to

```
[ -f ../test/*.txt ]
```

which gets expanded.

It is a little bit dangerous to use `$FILE` to hold a pattern: if your `"$1"` contains a space, you cannot make it work either quoted or unquoted: quoted will keep the space, but asterisk too, but unquoted will split at the space. You could play with `IFS`, but in this case, an intermediate variable isn't the best idea anyway.

People will cringe at this hack, but if don't have pathological filenames, it will work. What you can do is, just force filename expansion before saving it in the variable.

```
FILE="$(echo ../"$1"/*.txt)"
```

Now, the asterisk is replaced with the actual filename, and later, you can safely use the quoted version `"$FILE"` to protect spaces, but the asterisk is gone.

This will fail if there is no file with that name, the asterisk will be kept literal (unless you set `nullglob` bash option). And if there is more than one txt file there, this won't work properly either. However, this will always work

```
for FILE in ../"$1"/*.txt; do whatever you want to do with `"$FILE"`; done
```

Comment: Another option is `find "../$1" -name "*.txt" -exec scp {} remoteserver \;`. Note that this will descend into subdirectories (if any) unless you tell it not to.